# Confirmation delete in .jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, confirm

I wish to have a confirmation on a delete button, and am attempting to do it all in one line... this is the regular onClick event without the delete confimration:

```
onClick='this.form.action="/Config?pg=FIBiller&amp;cmd=delete";'
```

I found online that a confirm delete can be implemented as such:

```
"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"
```

How can I incorporate this into my onClick event so it's one line, don't want to use more javascript? If I must do so, than how would I incorporate the action for a "yes" on the message box in the javascript function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just want

```
<form action="/Config?pg=FIBiller&amp;cmd=delete">
    <input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
</form>
```

Or if you really can't change your form as such for some unclear reason (bad design maybe?), then you need to introduce an `if-else` block as follows which changes the form's action on confirmation and returns `false` on cancel.

```
<input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) form.action='/Config?pg=FIBiller&amp;cmd=delete'; else return false;" />
```

Note: if you want to add more calls or want to improve readability, introduce braces:

```
<input type="submit" value="delete" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) { form.action='/Config?pg=FIBiller&amp;cmd=delete'; } else { return false; }" />
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I'd suggest to get rid of `cmd=delete` as you could also just check that by giving the delete button a name so that it will be sent as request parameter as well:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" ...>
```

you could then check as follows in the JSP/Servlet side if it's been pressed:

```
if (request.getParameter("delete") != null) {
    // Delete button is pressed.
}
```

By the way, deleting by GET is a bad idea. Rather use POST. Otherwise all delete links will be executed when a searchbot comes along your website and crawls all GET links/actions without executing JavaScript. You also don't want the resulting delete requests to be bookmarkable, right?

Comment: thanks for all the valuable info.. yes using POST not GET.
does not seem to work, syntax error perhaps? getting 404 error on "yes" click, button code below....

       <% if (!isAddPage) { %>    
            <button class="button" id="t4button3" type="submit" style="margin-left: 20px" onClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) form.action='/Config?pg=FIBiller&amp;cmd=delete'; else return false;">
                <span class="ss_sprite ss_delete"><fmt:message key="fiBiller.button-delete" bundle="${configRc}"/></span>
            </button>
            <%} %>

Comment: You're welcome. Oh okay, I already wondered the usage of the query string in the action method. You'd rather use a `<input type="hidden" name="pg" value="FIBiller">` in the form instead and let the server side just check if the button is pressed by appearance of its name as request parameter.

Comment: As to the 404 error, this just means that the URL is wrong. Perhaps you need to prepend the context path? I just copied the URL from your question assuming that it's already correct and that webapp runs on root. Fix it as follows: `form.action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Config?...'`. Or make it a relative URL instead: `form.action='Config?...'` this assumes the servlet to be in the "same folder" as the current JSP.

Comment: still get 404 error. i checked the link and it is correct, the one I wrote and the one you wrote.
`<button class="button" id="t4button3" type="submit" style="margin-left: 20px" onClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) { this.form.action='/Config?pg=FIBiller&amp;cmd=delete'; } else { return false; }">
                <span class="ss_sprite ss_delete"><fmt:message key="fiBiller.button-delete" bundle="${configRc}"/></span>
            </button>`

Comment: Click the button and look at browser address bar. It will appear as `http://example.com/Config?...`. Is this correct? Or is this supposed to be `http://example.com/somecontextpath/Config?...`? If so, re-read my previous comment.

Comment: Hi Balus, i've seen and understood the previous post unfortunately it does not work. the path is as such 'http://example.com/Config?.'
never the less you have provided much useful information. thank you for your time!